# Migrating from aws sdk 1 to aws sdk 2->The import io.awspring cannot be resolved

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am trying to migrate my spring-boot code from aws sdk 1 to aws sdk 2 for dynamoDb. I am referring to https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-cloud-aws-dynamodbtemplate/.
But I am facing one issue with the above dependency. This is my build.gradle file. Please guide what I am doing wrong?

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'

implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.25.6') 
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb-enhanced'
implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-dynamodb'
implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter'

// annotation processors
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
}
```